# Refactor code to don't use typeof for references

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

I have below code which is from Enum creating enum + functionality for each value of it.

I would like to get rid of these 2x "typeof" is it doable?

```
const TEST = createEnumComparator<typeof Test, SuperCompareEnums<typeof Test>>(Test, SuperCompareEnums);
```

This is what I would like to get and do the same

```
const TEST = createEnumComparator<Test, SuperCompareEnums<Test>>(Test, SuperCompareEnums);
```

Or something like this would be the best

```
const TEST = createEnumComparator<SuperCompareEnums<Test>>(Test, SuperCompareEnums);
```

Whole code

```
class CompareEnums<T> {
  constructor(protected value: keyof T) {

  }

  public is(value: keyof T) {
    return value === this.value;
  }
}

class SuperCompareEnums<T> extends CompareEnums<T> {
  sayHello() {
    console.log('hello ' + this.value);
  }
}

interface Constructor<T> {
  new(...args: any[]): T;
}

function createEnumComparator<TObj1, TObj2 extends CompareEnums<TObj1>>(obj1: TObj1, obj2: Constructor<TObj2>): EnumAsComparator<TObj1, TObj2> {
  return _.mapValues<any>(obj1, value => new obj2(value)) as any;
}

// --------------------------------------------


enum Test {
  A = 'A',
  B = 'B'
}

const TEST = createEnumComparator<typeof Test, SuperCompareEnums<typeof Test>>(Test, SuperCompareEnums);

// --------------------------------------------
console.warn(1111111111111);
console.warn(TEST.A.is(Test.A), 1);
console.warn(TEST.B.is(Test.B));
console.warn(TEST.B.sayHello());
console.warn(TEST.A.is(Test.B));

// --------------------------------------------

type EnumAsComparator<TObj1, TObj2> = {
  [P in keyof TObj1]: TObj2;
};
```

Comment: What would go against using `any`? Isn't the problem that `enum` is not really a reference type, but the properties are just inferred (as they have to be constant upon compilation time). I mean, I created an interface say `ITest` with `A` & `B` as properties and I could call your code with `ITest` instead of `typeof Test`, but that beats the purpose of your `createEnumComparator` so, I ask again, if you want `typeof` gone, what stops you from using `any`? :)

Comment: I would like to just get rid of "typeof" the rest should stay. I preffer to change types inside implementation of this function than each type use typeof XXX